# Which one of the following passive voice is correct?

Tags: passive-voice, personal-pronouns

"We saw you and him." 
If I change the above sentence to passive voice, which one of the following would be correct ?

1. "He and you were seen by us."
2. "You and he were seen by us."

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(he+and+you+were)%2C(you+and+he+were)&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28he%20and%20you%20were%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28you%20and%20he%20were%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

Either one is proper passive construction, and they convey the same meaning.

The only difference is in how you chose the order of the pronouns "he" and "you". This is entirely at your preference, and does not alter the correctness of your passive voice construction.

(Of course, if this was a test question, the teacher would probably not want you to reverse the pronouns.)